# How to find thickness of segmented part of image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, thickness

I want to find the average thickness of a part which I am segmented, so I want to find the average pixel length in between the two borders (see below). How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: If I answered with something as broad as you have asked,  I would say "using `diff` or subtracting one vector from another". Please show us how you are storing the line data, a relevant sample of code etc to make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the pdist 2 function:

```
A = [1,3; 
     2,3; 
     3,3];
B = [1,4; 
     2,5; 
     3,6];

dist = pdist2(A,B,'Euclidean','Smallest',1)

mean(dist)
```

This calculates the smallest distance possible between every point in the two vectors, and then returns the mean of this.

Comment: How can we express one pixel in terms of micrometer

Comment: need to find out how pixels per micrometer there are in your image and then multiply by this number